# Combining two list into one using an equal variable

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm having an issue with creating a combined list as of right now I create two list from a response value. Like so below

This is my Ip address list

```py
# Creates an appended list containing interface name and ip
IPresponse = response['ietf-interfaces:interfaces']['interface']

global IPList
IPList = []

for dev in IPresponse:
    IPList.append(
        {'Interface Name': dev['name'], 'Ip Address': dev['ietf-ip:ipv4']})

print(IPList)
return IPList
```

This is MAC address list. I would like to combine these two list.

```py
# Creates a appended list containing interface name and MAC address
MACresponse = response['ietf-interfaces:interfaces-state']['interface']

global MAClist
MAClist = []

for dev in MACresponse:
    MAClist.append({'Interface Name': dev['name'],
                    'Physical Address': dev['phys-address']})

print(MAClist)
return MAClist
```

How I'm combining the list is like the following:

```py
def combinedlist(IPList, MAClist):
    combinedlist = ['']
    for ipdict in IPList:
        for macdict in MAClist:
            if ipdict['Interface Name'] == macdict['Interface Name']:
                combinedlist.append({'name': ipdict['Interface Name'],
                                     'ip': ipdict['Ip Address'],
                                     'MAC Address': macdict[
                                         'Physical Address']})
                print(combinedlist)
```

I'm trying to combine them from using the interface name to make sure that the correct information for each interface is with the corresponding interface. right now I'm having issues with an error that says *"function object not iterable"* but in general I think this is a little messed up and was wondering anyone would be able to help.

Thank you

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: python3.9 sorry for not clarifying

Comment: Why do you use lists at all? Keeping a single dict of interface names would make all of this a whole lot easier. If ordering is important, you can have a dict of dicts and add an "index" member which increments monotonically as you add new members to the outer dict.

Comment: Because I'm pulling these list from a cisco switch and trying to iterate the interfaces

Answer (score 0):

The Pythonic way to do this would be to use a dictionary keyed by the interface name to gather the combined info, which simplifies your whole code down to this:

```py
# Creates an appended list containing interface name and ip
IPresponse = response['ietf-interfaces:interfaces']['interface']

combined_info = {}

for dev in IPresponse:
    combined_info[dev['name']] = {'ip': dev['ietf-ip:ipv4']}

# Creates a appended list containing interface name and MAC address
MACresponse = response['ietf-interfaces:interfaces-state']['interface']

for dev in MACresponse:
    combined_info[dev['name']]['MAC Address'] = dev['phys-address']
```

Note that this assumes that all the same interface names occur in both IPresponse and MACresponse, which it would appear is the case.

To be functionally equivalent to your code and only gather values which have both an IP address and a MAC you can add some extra logic and filtering at the end.

```
# Creates an appended list containing interface name and ipIPresponse = response['ietf-interfaces:interfaces']['interface']

combined_info = {}

for dev in IPresponse:
    combined_info[dev['name']] = {'ip': dev['ietf-ip:ipv4']}

# Creates a appended list containing interface name and MAC address
MACresponse = response['ietf-interfaces:interfaces-state']['interface']

for dev in MACresponse:
    # This check is optional, depends on the nature of response
    devname = dev['name']
    if devname in combined_info:
        combined_info[devname]['MAC Address'] = dev['phys-address']

# another optional cleanup
combined_info = {devname, info for devname, info in combined_info.items() if 'MAC Address' in info}
```

PS: It might be worth having a look at [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)